# pyspark DataFrame selectExpr is not working for more than one column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We are trying Spark DataFrame `selectExpr` and its working for one column, when i add more than one column it throws error.

First one is working, the second one throws error.

**Code sample:**

```
 df1.selectExpr("coalesce(gtr_pd_am,0 )").show(2)
 df1.selectExpr("coalesce(gtr_pd_am,0),coalesce(prev_gtr_pd_am,0)").show()
```

**Error log:**

```
>>> df1.selectExpr("coalesce(gtr_pd_am,0),coalesce(prev_gtr_pd_am,0)").show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1216, in selectExpr
    jdf = self._jdf.selectExpr(self._jseq(expr))
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco
    raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input ',' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 21)\n\n== SQL ==\ncoalesce(gtr_pd_am,0),coalesce(prev_gtr_pd_am,0)\n---------------------^^^\n"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this

```
df1.selectExpr("coalesce(gtr_pd_am,0)”,”coalesce(prev_gtr_pd_am,0)").show()
```

You need specify the columns individually